# In Sencha Touch how can I push to a new view when clicking a button?

Tags: view, sencha-touch-2

I have the following button within a Panel within a view:

```
items: [
    {
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'SEND',
        ui: 'confirm',
        docked: 'bottom',
        handler: function(){
            view.push('TouchNuts.view.Transactions',{
                title: 'New views title',
                html: 'Some content'
            });
        }
    }
]
```

I would like to navigate to a page that consists of a list `'TouchNuts.view.Transactions'` when I click it.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`view` needs to be a reference to your NavigationView. One way of getting that reference is by giving it an `id` and then using `Ext.getCmp` to fetch the component:

```
{
    xtype: 'navigationview',
    id: 'my-id',
    items: [...]
}

Ext.getCmp('my-id');
```

Comment: I'm so lost man.  I have a good understanding of html, css and jQuery but no JS or SenchaTouch.  I put `{
    xtype: 'navigationview',
    id: 'my-id',
    items: [...]
}`  within config and than put `id: 'my-id',` on the view I wanted to show when clicking a button, and `Ext.getCmp('my-id`);` at the bottom of my file, but obviously nothing worked.  Do u know of any tutorials that explains step by step how to simply push a new view at the click of a button?  Thanks.